# ETIMEDOUT Error on EC2 with Sendgrid API v3

Tags: node.js, nestjs, amazon-ecs, sendgrid

I am using @sendgrid/mail to send emails from my nestjs application. Works fine while testing locally but its throwing ETIMEDOUT on my EC2 instances with a load balancer managed by ECS. Is there some config that I am missing to make it work on EC2?

My email.service

```js
export class EmailService {
  constructor() {
    SendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  }

  async sendMail(mail: SendGrid.MailDataRequired) {
    try {
      const transport = await SendGrid.send(mail);
      return transport;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }
```

Error logged on EC2

```
{
"message":"connect ETIMEDOUT 54.248.129.79:443",
"name":"Error",
"stack":"Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.248.129.79:443
 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)",
"config": {
"transitional":{
"silentJSONParsing":true,
"forcedJSONParsing":true,
"clarifyTimeoutError":false
},
"transformRequest":[null],
"transformResponse":[null],
"timeout":0,
"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
"xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
"maxContentLength":null,
"maxBodyLength":null,
"headers":{
"Accept":"application/json",
"Content-Type":"application/json",
"User-Agent":"sendgrid/7.7.0;nodejs",
"Authorization":"Bearer <token>",
"Content-Length":22019
},
"url":"/v3/mail/send",
"method":"post",
"data": { ...data },
}
```

ECS task definition (with some values removed)

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "image": "",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "portfolio-backend-3000-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 3000,
                    "hostPort": 3000,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "AWS_REGION",
                    "value": "ap-southeast-1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME",
                    "value": "86400"
                },
                {
                    "name": "PORT",
                    "value": "3000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AWS_BUCKET_NAME",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "SENDGRID_API_KEY",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "DATABASE_URL",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "JWT_SECRET",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
                    "value": ""
                },
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "executionRoleArn": "",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 6,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "512",
    "memory": "307",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "",
    "registeredBy": "",
    "tags": []
}
```

Load balancer and EC2 instances configured to accept all inbound traffic and outbound ipv4 traffic

Also tried using axios instead of sendgrid's @sendgrid/mail but still facing the same issues

cURL requests from within the instances work

Tested `telnet 54.248.129.79 443` on my ec2 instances and have no issues connecting

Comment: You have this tagged with `ecs` not `ec2`. Are you running this in an container managed by ECS? Or are you running the code directly on EC2?

Comment: container is managed by ECS

Comment: The container could have completely different network access than the EC2 instance it is running on, depending on the network mode you selected when you configured the ECS task. You have provided **zero** information about the ECS configuration, I only happened to notice that you had tagged the question with `ecs`. Please provide the ECS task definition in your question.

Comment: I have included the task definition, apologies

Comment: You are using `awsvpc` network mode, which means the task gets its own Elastic Network Interface. So the ECS task/service will have its own security group as well. What are the outbound rules of the security group attached to the ECS task?

Comment: I’m allowing all outbound traffic on ipv4, but still can’t do api calls even though I’ve enabled internet gateway on the vpc. In the end I ditched sendgrid and am using nodemailer with amazon ses